# can we select android softkeyboard in different language selecting from a language list?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to select android soft keyboard in different language choosing from a languages listed that are supported by the devices.

Comment: NO, you cant. you must have to create custom keyboards for particular languages for that..

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have check which language do you wan to provide and check it beside to space bar there is settings button by going to there you can check which ever language you want to provide and after that completion try below once...

In the main phone settings you can choose input languages and then you can swipe the space bar to switch.